# Division by 1 in programming languages

Tags: division, integer-division, relational-division

So what if we tell a programming language to calculate this: 
X/1, where X is any number. Do they actually calculate the output or check/ignore 1 and return X?

Furthermore, when coding something like the above is it worth checking if the divider is 1 or is it faster to just let it compute the division anyway?

Thank you

---

In order to elaborate on this question: Which is faster?

```
$result = $number / $divisor;
```

or

```
$result = $divisor > 1 ? $number / $divisor : $number;
```

Comment: one is a power of 2, so it should be translated to a right-shift (of zero), which in turn is a no-op. i would guess.

Comment: The compiler / optimizer will get rid of it. If it is a runtime parameter, you still don't want to check, because usually you have seldom 1 as a divisor. Btw, division is usually done by some iterative algorithm. It will converge very fast when using 1. Thus it is not that much of an issue.

Comment: @sp2danny: Only true when the compiler knows about the value. For user input you'd need a JIT to find that out.

Comment: Division is usally done using the DIV CPU instruction, I'd wager

Comment: @neuhaus: And how is the DIV DBPU instruction working internally...?

Comment: Does it matter as long as it's fast?

Comment: I love that my question got voted down but people comment on it :) apart from that, do we know about PHP/C++ compilers what they will do on that case? in my application its 50/50 that it will hit a divider of 1.

Comment: I wouldn't bother optimizing it unless it's a huge performance issue.

Comment: @neuhaus while everything on the desktop has had single-cycle integer divide for fifteen or twenty years, ARMv7 does not necessarily have it. So there are still quite a few hundreds of millions of devices in use with a soft integer divide. But, no, I wouldn't bother hand optimising it either. That's crazy.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array

Answer (score 2):

Most programming languages will probably not check for special divisors (with the exception of 0).

CPUs are very fast at division nowadays so it's not worth checking beforehand. The checks could take longer than the actual division.

Comment: most compiler DO check for special divisors, if it can happen compiletime

Answer (score 2):

Comparing the examples (at least for PHP):

```
<?php
$divisor = 1;
for ($i=0; $i<100000000; $i ++ ) {
if ($divisor != 1)  
    $a = $i / $divisor;
else
    $a = $i;
}
```

takes `6.9s` on my machine. The other one:

```
<?php
$divisor = 1;
for ($i=0; $i<100000000; $i ++ ) {

    $a = $i / $divisor;
}
```

takes only `5.2s`

So to answer the final question, which one is faster: just let it compute the division :-)

Comment: don't you mean `if ($divisor != 1)`?

Comment: You're right, @neuhaus. I corrected the code and modified the time. It's still faster to not compare it though.

Answer (score 0):

Since a check and a jump + the actual division would be more cpu instructions than just doing the division, I'm pretty certain that it will just be done.

If your code is variable / 1 (the 1 being static) the compiler will most likely optimize it away.